# How can we have two independent parameters (physically) during Rabi Oscillations happening in Rydberg Atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-computer, rabi-model, rydberg-states

Rabi Oscillations are explained as electric interaction between atom and EM field, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495374/detuning-in-rabi-oscillations). This can be true for any two-level system with specific interactions that can lead to the Hamiltonian given in the [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29401/a-two-level-system-absorbs-a-detuned-photon-where-does-the-extra-energy-go) with two important terms, one is detuning frequency and the other is external EM field frequency.

Now, my question is about Rabi Oscillations happening in some Rydberg atoms. Having two **independent-tunable-parameters** means that you can control both the frequency of the EM field and the energy difference between the two levels. Now, how can we do the latter in these atoms? In normal atoms where two levels were split using a magnetic field, tunable detuning is possible. But for Rydberg atoms having different values of principle quantum number for **occupied electronic states**, I am not sure how can we achieve it.

PS: Context: I am reading about [neutral atom quantum computing](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_neutral_atoms/). They have a kind of Hamiltonian I am talking about. But the question is more general to computing, because of which I asked it here.

Answer (score 0):

The excited-state energy of one Rydberg atom changes when another Rydberg atom is brought close to it, in an effect known as the Rydberg blockade (due to strong dipole-dipole interactions between two electrons in highly excited Rydberg levels that tend to favour only one of the electrons being able to occupy that level). Therefore, the extra independent parameter to control the energy level of one Rydberg atom is the distance between your Rydberg atom and another Rydberg atom. By moving your (or the other) atom in physical space, you change the energy levels (energy includes an interaction term, which changes with distance).

Comment: I know that. I needed to emphasize that mathematically among three terms I can have two time-dependent parameters, rabi drive and detuning drive. I can control them independently at least according to the Hamiltonian. But I am not able to make sense how is it possible physically.

Comment: @Prabhat Are you asking how to change a laser's frequency and intensity at the same time?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have added a little more context to the problem. Please have a look and let me know.